# BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Received is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods .add_Received

Tags: c#, .net, events, bluetooth-lowenergy, mscorlib

I am following a video tutorial about Bluetooth connection uploaded to this github repository specific code file https://github.com/angelsix/blueberry/blob/master/Source/Blueberry.Desktop.WindowsApp.Bluetooth/DnaBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.cs, but following the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVasdDtgLKY) steps so my actual code is like following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement;
using Windows.Foundation;

namespace BluetoothConnection.Desktop.BluetoothDotNet
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps and makes use of the <see cref="BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher"/>
    /// for easier consumption
    /// </summary>
    public class DnaBluetoothBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher
    {
        #region Private Members

        /// <summary>
        /// The underlying bluetooth watcher class
        /// </summary>
        private readonly BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher mWatcher;

        #endregion

        #region Public Events

        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the bluetooth watcher stops listening
        /// </summary>
        public event Action StoppedListening = () => { };

        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the bluetooth watcher starts listening
        /// </summary>
        public event Action StartedListening = () => { };

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// The default constructor
        /// </summary>
        public DnaBluetoothBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher()
        {

            // Create bluetooth listener
            mWatcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher
            {
                ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active
            };

            // Listen out for new advertisements
            mWatcher.Received += WatcherAdvertisementReceived;

            // Listen out for when the watcher stops listening
            mWatcher.Stopped += (watcher, e) =>
            {
                // Inform listeners
                StoppedListening();
            };
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Listens out for watcher advertisements
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The watcher</param>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments</param>
        private void WatcherAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
        {

        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The problem I have is I can't get it to work because it throws me the following error:
Property, indexer, or event 'BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Received' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods 'BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.add_Received

[image]

I barely know from the error that I need to use add_Received method, but there is no documentation nor code snippets to use that method around all internet, even stackoverflow.

What is the correct way to use the function so I can add events to the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher?

I am frustrated from doing this for about 3 days.

However I use it, even with the help of ChatGPT, I get the error "mscorlib not found".

Comment: What framework are you targeting?

Comment: I am targetting framework 4.8, using VS Community 2022, and using .NET 8.0, also, was using windows target 10.0.19041.0 (Windows 10 SDK)

Comment: Okay, did installing the respective SDK if not done yet, and most importantly adding a reference to the `Windows.winmd` file from my answer help then?

Comment: What is the respective SDK, I don't know which is it and how to install it, I read that specific words "Respective/Compatible SDK" but I didn't someone to ask to. I don't even know if what I did was the correct configuration

Comment: The SDKs are available from the "Visual Studio Installer" which should be available from the Windows Start Menu. For the VS2022 entry, you click on "Modify", and in the now opening installation management window, go to the "Individual Components" tab and filter for "Windows SDK". See if some framework is already installed, and find the Windows.winmd file from that version (see the ".NET Framework" section of my answer).

Answer (score 0):

`BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` was only introduced in Windows 10.0.10240. You need to set the target OS to Windows and the OS version to at least 10.0.10240.0.

I actually have multiple projects using the `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher`, and these are the project configurations that work on my machine:

### .NET (Core)

In the *.csproj file, I set the target framework to `net6.0-windows10.0.17763`. Then I added `using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement;` and was able to attach a delegate.

---

### .NET Framework

I set the target framework version to `v4.7.2` and added a reference to the `Windows.winmd` file from the Windows 10 or 11 SDKs. My current setup is using the file from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.22000.0\` which is the "Windows 11 SDK". You can install these SDKs from the VS Installer's "Individual components" tab; just search for "Windows SDK" to get a list of the available kits, any kit newer than 10.0.10240.0 will do. I think the oldest SDK available is 10.0.18362.0 already, so that should work as well.

I also included a reference to the `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll` to get access to the `CopyTo(this IBuffer source, byte[] destination)` extension, which is useful to deal with the `Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer` objects that many BLE methods use. I found this DLL in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\` which I could reference even though this is a framework project.

Comment: What is to attach a delegate?

Comment: Writing `mWatcher.Stopped += () => { ... }` is called "attaching a lambda function to the event", likewise `mWatcher.Stopped += OnWatcherStopped` is called "attaching a [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)" since events are built on delegates.